# Rails for zombies level 5 video: Why wouldn't tweets_path work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to, rails-for-zombies

I have a question about the 5th video 'Routing into darkness'.
At about 3 minutes 44 seconds Greg is describing how to set up a link_to using a custom route. A line appears saying "tweets_path wouldn't work".
I'd like to know WHY tweets_path wouldn't work. I'm hoping knowing why will help demystify Rails some more. At the moment that line seems a bit arbitrary and I'd like to make sense of it.

**EDIT**

Sorry, for some reason I was thinking you'd need to see the video. Here's the relevant code:
In his routes.rb file:

```
get '/all' => 'tweets#index'
```

And in a view, somewhere:

```
<%= link_to "All Tweets", ?? %> # tweets_path wouldn't work
```

Comment: Please do consider adding few lines of coding. that will clear the question ?

Comment: Very difficult to get the context out of what your question is? Why did Greg say `"tweets_path wouldn't work`?

Comment: This is a long shot but what Greg might be referring to is you need to use an absolute URI when creating a redirect instead of just the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tweets_path` won't work here because there isn't a route called 'tweets_path' in his routes.rb file. The only routes that he has (at least that we can see) is the '/all' route, which goes to the tweets controller and index action. If Greg put `resources :tweets` in his routes.rb file, then `tweets_path` would work. Also, if you have the code `get '/all' => 'tweets#index'` (i.e. without `as: 'all_tweets'`), then `all_path` will work. With `as: 'all_tweets'`, then only `all_tweets_path` will work

Comment: Thanks for taking the time and (I assume) re-watching the video. I've added the code, above. Your answer sounds sensible to me. I'm finding it hard to remember which routes Rails generates from which syntax. I really wish there were more 1-1 correlations between things. Slowly getting there.